# VC++: #import directive: how to specify a library version?

Tags: visual-c++, com, import, ms-office, typelib

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx), there is version attribute but if you specify a wrong version number VC still compiles the code. For example:

```
// MSO.DLL (Microsoft Office, Object Library)
//  Office 10.0 => version(2.2)
//  Office 11.0 => version(2.3)
//  Office 12.0 => version(2.4)
#import "libid:2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52" version(123.456) //< wrong version.
```

How to force the compiler to fail on such code? I would like to use only specific version of type-library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The rules are explained in LoadRegTypeLib:

> LoadRegTypeLib compares the requested version numbers against those
>   found in the system registry, and takes one of the following actions:
>
> - If one of the registered libraries exactly matches both the
>     requested major and minor version numbers, then that type library is
>     loaded.
> - If one or more registered type libraries exactly match the
>     requested major version number, and has a greater minor version number
>     than that requested, the one with the greatest minor version number is
>     loaded.
> - If none of the registered type libraries exactly match the
>     requested major version number (or if none of those that do exactly
>     match the major version number also have a minor version number
>     greater than or equal to the requested minor version number), then
>     LoadRegTypeLib returns an error.

Your case matches the 2nd bullet, not the 3rd.  Microsoft does spend a lot of effort on making these type libraries backward compatible.  Not taking advantage of it is easy to do.  Build your project on a machine with the right type library.  Copy the generated .tlh and .tli files to your project directory and check them in.  Replace the #import with #includes for those files.